# How to save the form with posted user in the django models database

Tags: python, html, django

I have created the login,authenticate,logout system, now I want to add a post functionality that saves the data in the Tweet model.

views.py

```
from .models import NameForm
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404

def home(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = NameForm(initial={'tweetedby':request.user.id}, datarequest.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return  redirect('home')
    else:
        form = NameForm()

    return render(request,'home.html',{"form":form} )
```

i am using the inbuild forms framework for the post request

home.html

```
<form method="post" novalidate>
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form }}
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

forms.html

```
from django.forms import  ModelForm
from django import forms

from .models import  Tweet


class NameForm(ModelForm):
    tweet = forms.CharField(label="tweet",max_length="50")


    def clean_tweet(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data["tweet"]
        return data

    class Meta:
        model = Tweet
        fields = ("tweet",)
```

when the user tweets i am getting the tweet and and the datetime form the tweet.but i want to access the tweeted_by user from the post request,

model.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Tweet(models.Model):
    tweet = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    tweetedtime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    tweetedby = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.tweet
```

I get the error

> null value in column "tweetedby_id" violates not-null constraint
> DETAIL:  Failing row contains (12, hi, 2020-06-07 09:55:20.482599+00, null)

The tweeted_by coloumb gets the null value without the USER id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set this in the view:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NameForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.tweetedby = request.user  # set user
            form.save()
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = NameForm()
    return render(request,'home.html', {'form':form})
```

The form should not contain any `tweetedby` field:

```
class NameForm(ModelForm):
    tweet = forms.CharField(label='tweet', max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        model = Tweet
        fields = ('tweet',)
```

in the model you can make the `tweetedby` field non-editable,, such that it does not appear by default in the form:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models

class Tweet(models.Model):
    tweet = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    tweetedtime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    tweetedby = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        editable=False
    )
```

A tweet has a maximum length of 280 characters, so perhaps 50 is too low.

> **Note**: You can limit views to a view to authenticated users with the
>   [**`@login_required`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).

Comment: it worked.thanks a lot.i just want  to know how you did it with the form.instance,are there any docs

Comment: @baluk: the `.instance` is the object wrapped in the form that is updated by the form. It is discussed for example here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-clean-method

Comment: i don't have a custom model,what should i set "AUTH_USER_MODEL" in the settings

Comment: @baluk: Normally you don't need to set it, by default it is `'auth.User'` (which is the default user model), so leaving it out of the settings will let it resolve to `'auth.User'`.

Comment: thanks a lot @willem van Onsem ,is there any way that i can contact you,like can you be my mentor